# Getting error while creating Azure Pipeline for uploading angular code to s3 bucket

Tags: npm, npm-install

I need to execute below command in an Azure Pipeline task:

```
npm config set registry http://*.*.*.*:*
```

I need to use my organizations registry for `npm`.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

try `https` in the command iinstead of `http`